# no_results in custom plugin?

Tags: plugin, no-results

Is there a way to return 'no results' from a custom plugin with the standard conditional of:

```
{if no_results}{/if}
```

I have resulted to using:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

} else {
    return $this->return_data = "<li><p>Sorry, no results</p></li>";
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course!

```
return $this->return_data = ee()->TMPL->no_results();
```

Or this, on the versions before 2.6:

```
return $this->return_data = $this->EE->TMPL->no_results();
```